# How to render global styles from styled-components in Storybook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, config, styled-components, storybook

Cannot render storybook application when trying to add global styles to the config file.

It was working before and when I tried to add the knobs addons it broke but I removed everything that has to do with the addon and it is still giving me issues

config.js

```
import React from 'react';
const { withPropsTable } = require('storybook-addon-react-docgen');
const req = require.context('../src/', true, /\.stories.jsx$/);
import { configure, addDecorator } from '@storybook/react';
import GlobalStyle from './../src/global/GlobalStyle';


function withGlobalStyles(storyFn) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <GlobalStyle />
      {storyFn()}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function loadStories() {
  req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename));
}

addDecorator(withPropsTable);
addDecorator(withGlobalStyles);
configure(loadStories, module);
```

Error:

ERROR in ./.storybook/config.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/.storybook/config.js: Unexpected token (22:2)

```
  20 | 
  21 | addDecorator((storyFn) => (
> 22 |   <div>
     |   ^
  23 |       <GlobalStyle />
  24 |       {storyFn()}
  25 |   </div>
```

It should render the application with global styles.

Comment: Hi,

I am having the same issue. Did you find a solution maybe?

Answer (score 0):

In storybook >6.X you can add decorators to your `preview.js` config file

```
//./storybook/preview.js

import { addDecorator } from "@storybook/react";
import GlobalStyle from "../path_to_your_styles/GlobalStyles";

addDecorator((story) => (
  <>
    <GlobalStyle />
    {story()}
  </>
));
```